# Fastest way to fill numpy array with distances from a point

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array that represents a 3d grid over a volume of space, with each cell representing a non-cubic voxel (the scaling is arbitrary in all three dimensions). The array is O(500) voxels per dimension.

I would like to fill that array with the distance from a given XYZ point to the center of each voxel.

I can fill the array by using python `for`-loops, but that's slower than I would like. Is there a way to do so quickly using numpy/scipy?

The conversion to XYZ coordinates is done with two tuples, one giving the XYZ coordinates of the center of the `0,0,0` voxel, and the other giving the size of the voxels in XYZ units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an ogrid with the distances in each dimension and then calculate the distance (using that the ogrid results broadcast correctly):

```
import numpy as np

x0, y0, z0 = 10, 10, 10

# assuming each dimension includes 500 points, from 0 to 500, step 1
x, y, z = np.ogrid[0:500, 0:500, 0:500]  
distances = np.sqrt((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2+(z-z0)**2)
```

If you need to include some scaling and offset for the grid:

```
x, y, z = np.ogrid[0:500, 0:500, 0:500]
x, y, z = (x * scale_x + offset_x, 
           y * scale_y + offset_y, 
           z * scale_z + offset_z)
distances = np.sqrt((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2+(z-z0)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create three one-dimensional arrays representing the flattened X, Y and Z coordinates of your 3D array.

Then you perform the hypothenuse calculation for the whole arrays, using numpy methods:

```
D = numpy.sqrt(numpy.power(X - x_center, 2) + 
               numpy.power(Y - y_center, 2) + 
               numpy.power(Z - z_center, 2))
```

At the end, you reshape the array to the original shape.

Comment: Why not use `np.square(x)` instead of `np.power(x, 2)`?